# need AES decryption example

Tags: aes, encryption

I need an obvious example about AES decryption. i just want to know how it works in order to make my own coding of this algorithm so, I neither want code nor algorithms, i just want some explanation of how it works, I need to understand it first before i can make an implemetation fir it. Can someone give me tutorials or references?

Comment: If you want neither code nor algorithms, then what do you want?!

Comment: Just explaination of how the decryption happens.

Comment: It is so tempting to provide:  `decrypted_data = aes_decrypt(key, encrypted_data);` as the answer.

Comment: "Neither code nor algorithms"? What else is there to a decryption example? Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: @Joe: What does it matter? We're not supposed to provide code. Seriously, what are we supposed to answer here? A lullaby about decryption in simple terms?

Comment: i want to know how the algorithm works, i want to know what are the exacatly steps happen to the state matrix in each round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about Moserware's [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)? It's clear and entertaining. Don't forget to sign and date the Foot-Shooting Prevention Agreement.

Comment: @March ,many thanx ,the explanation is abvious and i hope i can understand it , in order to make my own AES decryption algorithm code .